# iOS App Groups no longer working

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

Just over a year ago I signed up for a free Apple developer account. All went well, I was able to build apps and deploy on my iPhone.

One of the apps also has an a Today extension and I created an app group to share data. The provisioning profiles I generated expired, and I can no longer deploy the app on device. It works fine on Simulator, of course.

When I build, I get this error:

> None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: com.apple.security.application-groups.

If I click "Fix issue", I get this:

> #### Communication with Apple failed
>
> Your account does not have sufficient permissions to modify containers.

Going to Capabilities (both the app and the extension have the same issue), in App Groups, I see [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ll8U.png)

Again, "Fix issue" doesn't do anything. Completely disabling App groups works, but I need this.

I opened the expired .mobileprovision files and noticed that under Entitlements->com.apple.security.application-groups, the group is there, while in the new files, the array is empty. And the most weird part is that somehow the group is there since it appears in XCode and I can select it, but just not in the right place, and this is probably why I get those errors.

I tried cleaning and building the project, deleting all provisioning files, certificates, I created a new project, I tried to create a new group but it didn't work (it just appeared in red), but I'm all out of options.

When I log in to developer.apple.com, anything I do redirects me to purchasing the membership for enrolment.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error message and solved it the following way:

Open in Xcode Menu
    Xcode|Preferences

And select the "Accounts" Tab:
[image: "Accounts" Tab].

Select your Apple-ID and Press "View Details" in the lower right.
In the following Popup you can see all your Provisioning Profiles.

And for each Profile you can see an "**Expires**" Date. In my case the
iOS Team Provisioning Profile was expired. It seems that these are valid
for one month only if you have a free developer account.

I renewed it by clicking "**Download all**". Afterwards I was able to successfully sideload again.

Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: I tried that and it downloads the files, but build fails with app groups enabled. The `com.apple.security.application-groups` node is empty. They are valid and the app works without app groups.

Comment: Strange - I have App Groups too. They continued to work afterwards for me.

Comment: Strange indeed. Would you please check something? Create a new app group and use it. Then, open the new provisioning profile files with text edit and see if the groups are there. This would help isolate the problem. Do you have your free account for more than a year?

Comment: Yes - it should be about a year ago.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create new provisioning profiles. For that you need a paid developer account. The `Fix Issue` button is risky and often doesn't work or messes up your settings.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I can't explain why after deleting the old provisioning profiles, building, clicking "Fix it" when I got the error, I got new files with a new expiration date. So I can still run the apps, it's just that the new files don't have the correct info in regards to App Groups. Can it be that Apple limits the functionality for free accounts after one year?
I don't really mind paying, but I'd like to be sure I need to.